# django prefetch related

Tags: django

Как по-правильному, без костылей, вытащить все Task'и, относящиеся к автозированному на данный момент user'у?

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
colour = models.CharField(max_length=7)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)



class Task(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
priority = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES_OF_PRIORITY, default=LOW)
date_until = models.DateTimeField()
status = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True)
project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Сейчас могу немного перепутать, но по-моему можно так: Task.objects.filter(project__user = request.user)

Comment: Благодарю!!!!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
projects = Project.objects.filter(user = request.user)
Task.objects.filter(project = projects)
```

Либо так

```
Task.objects.filter(project__user = request.user)
```

Comment: Просто ОГРОМНЕЙШЕЕ СПАСИБО